# How to get a SUM of an attribute in Sphinx?

Tags: php, sphinx

I have Sphinx Search running on production, performing search with keywords, accessed through official sphinxapi.php. Now I need to output a sum of an attribute called price along with search results, similar to SQL query "SELECT SUM(t.price) from table_name t WHERE condition". This data is supposed to be displayed on a web page like "Showing 1 - 10 out of 12345 results, total cost is $67890". As documentation says, SUM() function is available when used with GROUP BY. However, the documentation does not provide enough details on implementation, googling and searching Stackoverflow doesn't help much as well.

Questions:

1. How should I group the search result?
2. Can it be performed with 1 Sphinx request, or do I have to get the search results first and then query Sphinx again to get the sum of found documents?

Please advise. An example will be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run a second query. The 'sum' is wanted on the WHOLE result set, whereas normal grouping, the aggregation is run per row. In your example, there is an implicit `GROUP BY '1'` which aggregates all rows.

So would need to use Grouping to do same in sphinx. 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#clustering

Using the aggregation function is relatively easy, use with setSelect, but not sure SetGroupBy has a syntax to group all rows so will have to emulate it.

```
//all normal setup need for normal query here
$cl->SetLimits($offset,$limit);
$cl->AddQuery($query, $index);

//add the group query
$cl->setSelect("1 as one, SUM(price) as sum_price");
$cl->setGroupBy("one",SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR); //dont care about sorting
$cl->setRankingMode(SPH_RANK_NONE); //no point actually ranking results. 
$cl->SetLimits(0,1);
$cl->AddQuery($query, $index);

//run both queries at once...
$results = $cl->RunQueries();

var_dump($results);
//$results[0] contains the normal text query results, use its total_found
//$results[1] second contains just the SUM() data
```

This also shows setting up as Multi-Queries!
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#multi-queries